# I paste the code given by twitter on my HTML but it keeps on saying "The markup in the document following the root elelment must be well informed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter

This is the code

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/crazyabtstyles" class="twitter-follow-button" data-show-count="false" data-size="large" data-show-screen-name="false">
Follow @crazyabtstyles
</a>

<script>!function(d,s,id){
    var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';
        if(!d.getElementById(id)){
           js=d.createElement(s);
           js.id=id;
           js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';
           fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);
        }
    }
   (document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');
</script>
```

Comment: where you put in inside html?

Comment: _informed_? Or did you meant _formed_? I would say that your markup (HTML) is not well formed.

Comment: What is this “it” that keeps saying that? And where do you put that fragment? It is well-formed (in the technical XML sense, which this seems to be about).

Comment: Please use copy and paste to show the *exact* error message.

Comment: Error parsing XML:The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

this is exactly what the message says.

Comment: and i am trying to copy paste code for the twitter button to my blog in Blogspot.